# Does an Is_Variable( ... ) kind of function exist in PHP?

Tags: php

If I have a string $foo defined as ...

```
$bar = "Hello World";
...
$foo = '$bar';
...
```

And a function that will use the string.

```
...
function doSomething( $foo )
{
   if( is_variable( $foo) )
   {
     // eval the variable and then use it.
   }
   else
   {
     //  just use the string as is
   }
}
```

Basically I want to be able to tell if the variable $foo itself contains a variable or is just a string.

That way when I call the function is_variable( ... ) I can evaluate the variable otherwise simply use the given string value.

Comment: [why?](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: Not sure how to answer this comment, because I need it in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [variables variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) if you want like this:

```
<?php

    $bar = "Hello World";
    $foo = 'bar';
          //^ Without the dollar sign

    if(isset($$foo)) {
           //^^ See here the double dollar sign
        echo $$foo;
    } else {
        echo "no";
    }

?>
```

Output:

```
Hello World
```

Comment: Yes, that would work, but the value I get is $foo = '$bar', it already contains the dollar sign.
I guess I could look for a starting dollar sign, and see if the value without the dollar sign is set.

Comment: @SimonGoodman Ah then just use this: `$foo = substr($foo, 1);` to get rid of the dollar sign

Answer (score 1):

`is_string`?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-string.php

So your function would become

```
function doSomething($foo)
{
   if(!is_string( $foo) )
   {
     // eval the variable and then use it.
   }
   else
   {
     //  just use the string as is
   }
}
```

Notice `if(!is_string( $foo) )` - the use of `!` - it's saying 'If $foo is **not** a string then....

Comment: That will not work if the function is a string but not a variable.
For example, $foo = "Hello" would return true for is_string( ... ) but it is not a variable. Whereas $foo = '$bar' is a string that contains the variable $bar.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use RegEx patterns for that. I wrote an example pattern:

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/aiR

```
function is_variable($var) {
  return preg_match("/^\$\w*$/", $var) == 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks great, but I am worried that this will not work in all cases, (but I could of course be wrong).
Does that regex apply to all valid php variable names? For example would it not return true for $foo = '$1ee' and it is not a valid variable name.

Comment: This pattern works with numbers, letters and underscores, you can try it on the posted link. Maybe you have to adjust the pattern for your needs (or read more about RegEx itself).

Comment: I agree, I was just saying that the proposed function in your answer is not exactly valid.